# Return Only The First Result For A Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm sure I know how to do this but my brain is letting me down right now

Take this example table showing vital signs readings taken from patients at various times of the day:

[image]

How do I return just the FIRST record for each day?  So that I end up with a result set like this:

[image]

Bear in mind that the records may not be conveniently in chronological order in the table as in this example.  I just want a query to find the lowest value in the ReadingTimestamp column for each PatientID and show the associated Temperature, Pulse and Respiration for that timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select y1.* from your_table y1
inner join 
(
  select patientid, min(readingtimestamp) as ts
  from your_table
  group by date(readingtimestamp), patientid
) y2 on y2.patientid = y1.patientid 
     and y2.ts = y1.readingtimestamp
```

Comment: This is the one I understand most easily and I've got it working, so I've marked it as the answer. I have to say, the query doesn't exactly run quickly, though!

Comment: May I add that this code does not run on Sql Server.... `Date` is not a valid function. Use `Convert(date, readingTimestamp)`.

Comment: @PhilipStratford: The performance problem lies within the need of a function to extract the date from a datetime. That makes indexes useless. If you need to speed it up you should think about splitting the datetime into 2 columns: date and time.

Answer (score 1):

As you would say it... but with a sub-query to eliminate all records except for the one that is the first one for each patient and date...

```
Select * From yrTable t
Where readingtimestamp = 
      (Select Min(readingtimestamp)
       From yrTable 
       Where PatientId = t.patientId
          And DateDiff(day, readingtimestamp, t.readingtimestamp) = 0)
```

Comment: @beth,     Thx for seeing typo!

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select PatitentId, ReadingTimeStamp, Temperature,Pulse Respiration from 
(Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By PatitentId order by ReadingTimeStamp) as Row,* 
from TableName
) T where Row=1
```